# Is there something similar to SqlServer's Switch Partition clause on Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

With Switch Partition clause we can switch the metadata of tables quickly as long they have the same schema. this very useful for synching tables between different systems.

Does postgres has a similar feature?

```
ALTER TABLE Table1
SWITCH PARTITION x TO Table2
```

PS: in SQL Server we have to truncate Table2 before doing the switching

Comment: `attach partition` maybe? Not sure what this does

Comment: it doesn't look the same :/ it looks more like adding to existing partition instead of switching between two tables.

Comment: Well, if you detach one partition and attach a new that has the same partition bounds it's essentially switching a partition. But again: you need to explain in detail what problem you are trying to solve and what this does exactly in SQL Server.

Comment: okay, let me find some time later today and I'll update this thread